# How to reduce image size from URL obtained from server? (React-native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have implemented fetch() request to call api which carries large number of images from server. I want that images to load in my application , but when i implemented it to swiper due to large size of image, application get crashed. can we resize that image by its url because i have only imageurl obtained as result. You can view my code as:`

```
render(){
var pages = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.props.items.length; i++) {
const imageURL = 'http://photoos.boondrive.com/'+ this.props.items[i].large_file_path + this.props.items[i].display_name;

pages.push(
  <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'black', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}} key={i}>
    <View>
      <Image
        style={{width:width,height:height}}
        source={{uri:imageURL}}>
        </Image>
    </View>
  </View>

);
}


return(
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
  <View>
  <AndroidToolBar title={'Photos'} navIcon={JResource.back} flowIcon={JResource.expandarrow}
  onPress={()=>this.props.navigator.pop()}/>
  </View>

  <Swiper style={{flex:1}} index={this.props.items.indexOf(this.props.item)}  loop={false}>
  {pages}
  </Swiper>

  </View>
);
}
```

}

I have guessed it that when i feed images into array large size of array is made, so that when it gets rendered, application allocates large memory which is nearly 255mb, therefore i cannot swipe all the images. Application gets hanged and gets crashed. How can i obtain my expected output and how can i optimize memory in this current problem. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: you can use fresco image loader which memory management is power full and it manage cache memory very well so, you have no longer of memory issues !!!
http://frescolib.org/

Comment: no i want it in react-native not in native android.

Comment: ok but you not mentioned react - native android